# "Illegal version" error with LFTP

Tags: linux, ftps, ftp

The following command:

```
lftp -c 'open -e "set ftps:initial-prot ""; \
set ftp:ssl-force true; \
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; \
set ssl:verify-certificate no; \
nlist ; " \
-u "username","password" \
ftps://server.domain.org:21'
```

Produces:

```
nlist: Fatal error: gnutls_handshake: A record packet with illegal version was received.
```

Running LFTP 3.7.11. Anyone have an idea what could cause this? I think I may need lftp with gnutls, but installing from source is not really an option on this server, and the only version I see available with yum includes only ReadLine.

```
# lftp -v
LFTP | Version 3.7.11 | Copyright (c) 1996-2009 Alexander V. Lukyanov
...
Libraries used: Readline 5.1
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize it didn't paste my whole thing.

Comment: According to [RFC 4127](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4217#section-9), the data channel protection (set via the `PROT` command) **must** be `C` (Clear) or `P` (Protected).  You configure `lftp` to use `set ftps:initial-prot ""`; you might instead try `set ftps:initial-prot "P"`.